# Dynamic HTML code being displayed on final result

Tags: list, html

Hello fellow SharePointers,

For some reason, the code below displays the HTML code on the page. Is there anyway I can remove it? Thanks.

```
HtmlTableCell question = new HtmlTableCell();
question.InnerText = "Question & Answer";
question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontStyle, "bold");
question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "#b8d1f3");
HtmlTableCell answer = new HtmlTableCell();


HtmlTableRow row = new HtmlTableRow();
row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "100%");
row.Cells.Add(question);
tableQuestions.Rows.Add(row);

for (int index = 0; index < jobQuestionnaires.Count; index++)
{
   HtmlTableRow r = new HtmlTableRow();
   question = new HtmlTableCell();
   question.InnerText = jobQuestionnaires[index]["QuestionText"].ToString();
   question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.FontStyle, "bold");
   question.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "gray");
   r.Cells.Add(question);
   tableQuestions.Rows.Add(r);

   r = new HtmlTableRow();
   answer = new HtmlTableCell();
   answer.InnerText = answers[index]["Answer"].ToString();
   answer.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "black");
   r.Cells.Add(answer);
   tableQuestions.Rows.Add(r);
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML text is coming because the fields are HTML enabled.

You can use below code to strip html tags

```
answer.InnerText = Regex.Replace(answers[index]["Answer"].ToString(), @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();
```

Do the same for questions